# $state.go is not loading all the functions in my js

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-service, angularjs-routing

I am trying to redirect to another url using state.go

```
$state.go("description-page", {disease: 'Thyroid'});
```

I am not even getting the scroll on the page. But when I refresh it, it works. Can anyone please help? 
Thanks.

Comment: Provide more code or plunker.

Comment: @SaiUniqui,its not possible for me to paste code since it was about 500 lines,what i am doubting is will $state.go() do same thing as ui-sref?

Comment: Yes. It does the same job.

Comment: Actually it's not related to your state, insert your codes here and tell us where you load ui-view

Comment: No related because when you route to that state some elements in your page not detect the routing , and after refreshing(F5) all elements will ready.

Comment: how ur refresh works? how ur page getting 'disease' param on refresh??

Comment: See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: In what state are you before calling state go? What is the hierarchical relation between the two states?

Comment: Hi all,its i resolved it by putting timeout.

Answer (score 0):

It resolved by putting timeout,

```
$timeout({
   $state.go("description-page", {disease: 'Thyroid'});
},1000)
```